# Mac thinks mouse is a keyboard

Tags: keyboard, mac, mouse, driver

Whenever I plug in my usb wireless mouse, my Macbook Air and Mac Pro both think that the mouse is a keyboard and won't register the mouse's movements at all. Is there a way to fix this?

The mouse is a cheapy Gigaware wireless usb mouse and I'm running OS X Mavericks.

Comment: Where are you being informed that it is a keyboard?

Comment: Have you tried the mouse on other computers?

Comment: @grgarside Probably the Keyboard Setup Assistant

Comment: The mouse most likely has extra buttons.

Answer (score 3):

This restored the default mouse behavior for me, though it looks like I had a different problem.

1. Open keyboard settings in System Preferences > Keyboard
2. Click `Modifier Keys...` button in bottom right of panel
3. Select your mouse from the dropdown
4. Click `Restore Defaults` button to restore default behavior.

If that doesn't work, you might also try these instructions for [removing your keyboard profiles](http://eng.raneri.it/blog/2009/01/17/how-to-reset-the-mac-keyboard/) and then restarting.

Comment: The `Restore Defaults` didn't work for me and the linked instruction are now outdated. That file doesn't exist on Mojave (10.14.6). Luckily mine started working after just restarting the computer.